# Nested Column doesn't Recompose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, jetpack-compose

I have nested column, when I click add button the goal is add another text field and when I click delete button (which still hidden because first index) the goal is remove its text field. It seems doesn't recompose but the list size is changed.

I have tried using LazyColumn and foreach inside leads to force close, still no luck.
Any help appreciated, thank you!

[image: Preview of the screen]

My current code :

```
@Composable
fun ProblemScreen() {
    val list = remember {
        mutableStateListOf<MutableList<String>>()
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
        repeat(3) {
            val listDesc = mutableListOf<String>()
            repeat(1) {
                listDesc.add("")
            }
            list.add(listDesc)
        }
    })

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
    ) {
        list.forEachIndexed { indexParent, parent ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(vertical = 8.dp, horizontal = 16.dp)
            ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Parent ${indexParent + 1}", fontSize = 18.sp)
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                    Button(onClick = {
                        parent.add("")
                        println("PARENT SIZE : ${parent.size}")
                    }) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Add, contentDescription = "Add")
                    }
                }
                parent.forEachIndexed { indexChild, child ->
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(top = 16.dp),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                        TextField(
                            value = "",
                            onValueChange = {

                            },
                            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(),
                            maxLines = 1,
                            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                        Button(
                            onClick = {
                                parent.removeAt(indexChild)
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier.alpha(if (indexChild != 0) 1f else 0f)
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Delete,
                                contentDescription = "Delete"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using mutable objects such as ArrayList<T> or mutableListOf() as state in Compose causes your users to see incorrect or stale data in your app. Mutable objects that are not observable, such as ArrayList or a mutable data class, are not observable by Compose and don't trigger a recomposition when they change. Instead of using non-observable mutable objects, the recommendation is to use an observable data holder such as State<List<T>> and the immutable listOf().

Comment: Can you provide an example for my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables), mutable objects that are not observable, such as mutableListOf(), are not observable by Compose and don't trigger a recomposition.

So instead of

```
val list = remember {
    mutableStateListOf<MutableList<String>>()
}
```

Use:

```
val list = remember {
    mutableStateListOf<List<String>>()
}
```

And when you need to update the List, create a new one:

```
//parent.add("")
list[indexParent] = parent + ""
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I have understand how I update the list by creating a new one. Can i ask how i assign text field value and onValueChange for the child? It seem doesn't change the value.

Comment: @Erwin Kurniawan A Same way - new list with replaced item, like `newList = oldList.toMutableList().apply{this[indexChild] = newValie}.toList()`

Comment: Thank you it works well. Somehow it doesn't change if I changed the List using my own data class, e.g `data class(val desc: String)` , any idea why?

Comment: Should work fine, can't say why it doesn't with given description

Comment: I tried with `data class Item(var desc: String)`. when I type, it doesn't change item.desc value. I have used `list[indexParent] = parent.toMutableList().apply { this[indexChild].desc = it }.toList()` and the text field still empty somehow, when I print, it only change 1 character.